# What does "her squashed-tomato of a nose" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At this, Winky howled even harder, her squashed-tomato of a nose dribbling all down her front, though she made no effort to stem the flow.

I think "*her squashed-tomato of a nose*" might refer to Winky's snot, that is, her snot is something like "squashed-tomato". Is my understanding correct?

From Harry Potter - the Goblet of Fire -- Chapter 21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is

> Her nose, which was looking like a squashed tomato

Thus

> At this, Winky howled even harder, her [**nose (resembling a squashed tomato)**] dribbling all down her front, though she made no effort to stem the flow.

"His/her something of a something" is a phrase commonly used to compare a face feature with some object. Examples from Google Books found using "his * of a nose/eye/ear":

> **His black dot of a nose** rested between his paws.
>
> If they knew that **his one grave slit of an eye** had seen gold in rice grains and furtive wealth in human lives, they were not prepared to abuse his memory, because Lung had stolen from them without vulgar ceremony
>
> Mad Jack stroked his chin, began fidgeting with the ring in **his gnarled lump of an ear**.

Comment: Can we also say "a squashed-tomato nose"? If so, any difference?

Comment: @dan - yes, we can - the difference I stylistic, I guess. The meaning would be the same.

Comment: @dan: The difference is semantic. The pattern "squashed tomato of a nose" calls the nose a squashed tomato; that is, it is a metaphor (however we interpret it) whereas in "a squashed-tomato nose"  the noun "squashed tomato" is a descriptor.  And you cannot generalize from this "translation" between forms; here they might be pretty much the same, but "a mountain of a man" and "a mountain man" are different things.

Comment: @dan That might make me wonder if her nose was actually a squashed tomato.  Consider "Frosty the Snowman" - `...with a corncob pipe and a button nose`, where here the snowman's nose is actually built using a clothing button.  If he had a `button of a nose`, however, it's clear that the expression is a metaphor.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Will it be the same to say "her nose of a squashed-tomato"?

Comment: @dan  No.  That would be calling the squashed tomato a nose, not the nose a squashed tomato.  The pattern is "{metaphorical thing} of a {actual thing}".  *Harry stared at Ron's pumpkin of a head.*

Answer (score 7):

Winky is a house-elf.  They have, from the human point of view, strange and rather ugly faces. In particular, Winky's nose looks something like a squashed tomato.

This is a known piece of imagery. There is a children's song

> My teacher's got a bunion
>   A face like a pickled onion,
>   A nose like a squashed tomato
>   And legs like matchsticks.

Answer (score 1):

Winky may have rhinophyma, a skin condition which causes the nose to become red and enlarged (sometimes also appearing flattened, if it enlarges more side-to-side). Historically people thought that alcoholism caused rhinophyma so the imagery of her having a large, red nose reinforces her alcoholism.

Also, her nose dripping is similar to a faucet dripping, the actual nose or faucet doesn't move but liquid comes out of it.